# Partial derivative of a function that isn't continuous

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Need some help to answer this question.

Consider the function $f : \mathbb{R}^{2} \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(0,0) = 0$ and

$f(x,y) = \frac{xy}{x^{2} + y^{2}}$ when $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$

Show that the partial derivatives exist at the point $(0,0)$ but the function is not continuous at the point $(0,0)$.

Comment: The partial derivatives at $(0,0)$ are not hard if you simply use the definition.

Comment: Okay, and to show that it's not continuous should I try and find the limits are $(0,0)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding what you said in a comment above, this is only to solve your second problem as to proving discontinuity.

By definition the map $f$ is continuous at $(0,0)$ iff $f(x,y) \to f(0,0)$ as $(x,y) \to (0,0);$ we claim that $f$ is not continuous at $(0,0)$. In fact, this follows immediately from noticing: for $y = 0$ we have $f(x,y) = 0$ for all $x \neq 0$; but $f(x,y) = \frac{1}{2}$ along the line $y = x$ except $(0,0)$, *i.e.* for $y = x \neq 0$ we have 
$f(x,y) = \frac{1}{2}$. This shows that $f$ is not continuous at $(0,0)$.